# Flask Request showing 400 Bad Request and redirects to '/' instead of '/someURL'

Tags: python, html, http, flask, request

I am creating an app to take info (sort of login) from **index.html** and then redirect to second html page **capture_simple.html**. But on sending post request from the second page the server show Error 400 and later redirects back to '/'  ('/' is where the error is shown) instead of remaining at '/captureSimple' .

This is my code for flask:

```
#imports
#app declaration
#__name__ stuff
@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    global processed_text
    text = request.form['text']
    processed_text = text.upper()
    make_a_dir(processed_text)
    #sends data for foldername to make_a_dir()
    return redirect(url_for('captureSimpleFunc'))




#captureSimple : to displey simple image    
@app.route('/captureSimple', methods=['GET','POST'])
def captureSimpleFunc():
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('capture_simple.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        xtr=request.form['flip']
        print(xtr)
        #some statements
        return xtr
```

So I have two html pages in my templates folder. On page **index.html**
This HTML page is not causing any trouble. I'm putting the code anyway.

```
    <body>
    <div id="container_1">
    <h1 class="all" id="head_name">OWL </h1>
    <h2 class="all" id="head_instru">Enter MR number</h2>
    <form class="all" action="." method="POST">

    </div><!-- 
        <input id="keyboard" type="text" class="ui-keyboard-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" >
        <input id="keyboard" type="text" > <br><br> -->
        <div id="wrap"> <!-- wrapper only needed to center the input -->

        <!-- keyboard input -->
        <input id="keyboard" type="text" name="text"><br><br>
        <input class="all" id="button_" type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send">
    </div> <!-- End wrapper -->

    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And then there is the second **capture_simple.html** page. This is where the real trouble is.

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action=".">
    <input type="submit" name="flip">
    </form> 
</body>
```

[ I have removed the unnecessary code above ]

My app is redirecting me to the second page, but on pressing the **flip** button in the form it is creating all **Bad Request error 400**.

The terminal shows something like:

> "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Answer (score 0):

So, I am answering my own question.

The problem was I had

```
action="."
```

in my form in **capture_simple.html**  file, so it was sending the request to the '/' root and creating all trouble.

Just drop the action attribute from the form and it works perfectly well.